# Removing all duplicates from the list - keeping no instance of a duplicate item

Tags: python, list, set, duplicates

I've got a list:

```
myList = [-3, -3, 6, 10, 10, 16, 16, 40, 40, 60, 60, 100, 100, 140, 140, 211, -8]
```

how can I efficiently remove all the duplicated items from the, i.e. to have a new list like this:

```
[6,211,-8]
```

I know a way to do it, by keeping a track of duplicated items, and then removing them using python set(), i.e.

```
listOfDuplicates = [x for x, y in collections.Counter(myList).items() if y > 1]
newList = list(set(myList) - set(listOfDuplicates))
```

Is there any better way of doing this (preserving the order) in python?

Comment: Turn that > around and ditch the second line. Or just use a set in the first place.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart You meant `==`, right? ;)

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes, sorry De Morgan :-)

Comment: Ignore the "or use a set" part of my comment; I misunderstood the problem statement. The first part still stands, however.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way is to invert the condition, as [suggested by Jonathon Reinhart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22760918/python-removing-all-duplicates-from-the-list-keeping-no-instance-of-a-duplicat/22761085#comment34697209_22760918)

```
import collections
print [x for x, y in collections.Counter(myList).iteritems() if y == 1]
# [6, 211, -8]
```

**Note:** This method will not be able to maintain the order of elements. For example, when

```
myList = [1, 1000, 10]
```

the result is

```
[1000, 1, 10]
```

Because `collections.Counter` is internally a dictionary only. As dictionaries use hashing, the order cannot be guaranteed.

To preserver Order, you can do like this, as [suggested by DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22760918/python-removing-all-duplicates-from-the-list-keeping-no-instance-of-a-duplicat/22761085#comment34697620_22761085)

```
c = Counter(myList)
print [x for x in myList if c[x] == 1]
```

Comment: If you wanted to preserve order, you could do `c = Counter(myList); nd = [x for x in myList if c[x] == 1]` or something.

Answer (score 0):

myList = [-3, -3, 6, 10, 10, 16, 16, 40, 40, 60, 60, 100, 100, 140, 140, 211, -8]

b=[]

d=[]

for x in myList:

```
  try:
      w=b.index(x)
      if w!=None:
           d.append(x)
           del b[w]
  except:
       b.append(x)
```

b=set(b)-set(d)

print list(b)

this will not preserve order too